# How to keep user from scrolling to portion of a page until an audio file has played for certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to block the user from scrolling past the "[just after]" picture of foggy trees until a certain point in the song is reached.

All the css is just font's and what not. I'd like to stop scrolling right before section SIX.

Here's the html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>LMC 3255 Project</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="morefonts.css">

<style>
    body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}
    body, html {
        height: 100%;
        color: #777;
        line-height: 1.8;
    }

    /* Create a Parallax Effect */
    .bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3, .bgimg-4, .bgimg-5, .bgimg-6, .bgimg-7 {
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    .bgimg-1 {
        background-image: url('images/snowyMountains.jpg');
    }
    .bgimg-2 {
        background-image: url('images/blackbirdEye.jpg');
    }
    .bgimg-3 {
        background-image: url('images/birdsInTree.jpg');
    }
    .bgimg-4 {
        background-image: url('images/birdsOfFire.jpg');
    }
    .bgimg-5 {
        background-image: url('images/areOne.jpg');
    }
    .bgimg-6 {
        background-image: url('images/justAfter.jpg');
    }
    .bgimg-7 {
        background-image: url('images/menOfHaddam.jpg');
    }

    .bgvid { 
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .animatedBG {
        animation-name: lightning;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }

    .w3-wide {letter-spacing: 10px;}
    .w3-hover-opacity {cursor: pointer;}
</style>

<body>
<audio autoplay>
  <source src="images/OpenCountryJoy.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

<!-- First Parallax Image with Title Text -->
<div class="bgimg-1 w3-display-container w3-opacity-min" id="home">
    <div class="w3-display-middle" style="white-space:nowrap;">
        <span class="w3-center w3-padding-xlarge w3-black w3-xlarge w3-wide w3-animate-opacity">BLACKBIRD</span>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Container-->
<div class="w3-content w3-container w3-padding-64" id="about">
    <h3 class="w3-center">Tucker LoCicero</h3>
    <p class="w3-center">
        A remediation of<br>
        <em>Thirteen Ways of Looking at a Blackbird</em><br>
        by Wallace Stevens<br>
    </p>
</div>

<!--ONE-->
<div class="bgimg-2 w3-display-container w3-opacity-min" id="stanza1bg">
    <div class="w3-display-middle">
        <span class="w3-xxlarge w3-text-light-grey w3-wide">ONE</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="w3-content w3-container w3-padding-64" id="stanza1">
    <h3 class="w3-center">Among twenty snowy mountains,<br>
        The only moving thing<br>
        Was the eye of the blackbird.<br>
    </h3>
</div>

<!--TWO-->
<div class="bgimg-3 w3-display-container w3-opacity-min" id="stanza2bg">
    <div class="w3-display-middle">
       <span class="w3-xxlarge w3-text-light-grey w3-wide">TWO</span>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="w3-content w3-container w3-padding-64" id="stanza2">
    <h3 class="w3-center">I was of three minds,<br>
        Like a tree<br>
        In which there are three blackbirds.<br>
    </h3>
</div>

<!--THREE-->
<div class="bgimg-4 w3-display-container w3-opacity-min" id="stanza2bg">
    <div class="w3-display-middle">
       <span class="w3-xxlarge w3-text-light-grey w3-wide">THREE</span>
   </div>
</div>


<div class="w3-content w3-container w3-padding-64" id="stanza3">
    <h3 class="w3-center">The blackbird whirled in the atumn winds.<br>
        It was a small part of the pantomime.<br>
    </h3>
</div>

<!--FOUR-->
<div class="bgimg-5 w3-display-container w3-opacity-min">
    <div class="w3-display-middle">
       <span class="w3-xxlarge w3-text-light-grey w3-wide">FOUR</span>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="w3-content w3-container w3-padding-64" id="stanza4">
    <h3 class="w3-center">A man and a woman<br>
        Are one.<br>
        A man and a woman and a blackbird<br>
        Are one.<br>
    </h3>
</div>

<!--FIVE-->
<div class="bgvid w3-display-container w3-opacity-min" id="stanza5bg">
    <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="bgvid">
        <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="w3-display-middle">
       <span class="w3-xxlarge w3-text-light-grey w3-wide">FIVE</span>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="w3-content w3-container w3-padding-64" id="stanza5">
    <h3 class="w3-center">I do not know which to prefer,<br>
        The beauty of inflections<br>
        Or the beauty of innuendoes,<br>
        The blackbird whistling<br>
        Or just after.<br>
    </h3>
</div>

<div class="bgimg-6 w3-display-container w3-opacity-min">
    <div class="w3-display-middle">
       <span class="w3-xxlarge w3-wide">[just after]</span>
   </div>
</div>

<!--SIX-->


<div class="w3-content w3-container w3-padding-64" id="stanza6">
    <h3 class="w3-center">Icicles filled the long window<br>
        With barbaric glass.<br>
        The shadow of the blackbird<br>
        Crossed it, to and fro.<br>
        The mood<br>
        Traced in the shadow<br>
        An indecipherable cause.<br>
    </h3> 
</div>

<!--SEVEN-->
<div class="bgimg-7 w3-display-container w3-opacity-min">
    <div class="w3-display-middle">
       <span class="w3-xxlarge w3-text-light-grey w3-wide">SEVEN</span>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="w3-content w3-container w3-padding-64" id="portfolio">
    <h3 class="w3-center">O thin men of Haddam,<br>
        Why do you imagine golden birds?<br>
        Do you not see how the blackbird<br>
        Walks around the feet<br>
        Of the women about you?<br>
    </h3>
</div>

<!--TEN-->
<div class="bgvid w3-display-container w3-opacity-min" id="stanza10bg">
    <video loop autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="bgvid">
        <source src="images/greenLight.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="w3-display-middle">
       <span class="w3-xxlarge w3-text-light-grey w3-wide">TEN</span>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="w3-content w3-container w3-padding-64" id="stanza10">
    <h3 class="w3-center">At the sight of blackbirds<br>
        Flying in a green light,<br>
        Even the bawds of euphony<br>
        Would cry out sharply.<br>
    </h3>
</div>

<!--THIRTEEN-->
<div class="w3-display-container w3-opacity-min">
    <img src="images/eveningAllAfternoon.jpg" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="w3-display-middle">
        <h3 class="w3-center w3-text-light-grey" style="font-size: 1000%">
            T<br>
            H<br>
            I<br>
            R<br>
            T<br>
            E<br>
            E<br>
            N<br>
        </h3>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="w3-content w3-container w3-padding-64">
    <h3 class="w3-center">It was evening all afternoon.<br>
            It was snowing<br>
            And it was going to snow.<br>
            The blackbird sat<br>
            In the cedar-limbs.
        </h3> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

See the [live website](https://tglocicero.github.io/BLACKBIRD/) (view on chrome).

Comment: Can you include `html`, `css` at Question?

Comment: You could disable scrolling: document.getElementsByTagName("body").style.overflow = "hidden"; on audio start and reenable it on audio end.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! I just made my div style="display: none" and used setTimeout() to fadeIn() at the right time.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {$("#somehiddenDiv").fadeIn();}, 7100);
    });
```